# Get relative path to XML file from a non-servlet class in a WAR

Tags: java, servlets, relative-path, war

I have an XML file which I need to read and load the data in memory every time the app launches. So, while the project was in Eclipse, i hardcoded the path: "/path/to/xml" but when I create the WAR, how can I specify the relative path to the XML file.

I can do it using `URL url = getServletContext().getResource(fileName);`

But, I don't have the servlet context available to me, since it's just a Config loader class.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I did this, was the simplest approach:

URL urlOfXml =

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("ConfigXmlFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). In the [`contextInitialized()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method which get called during webapp's startup you've got a handle to [`ServletContextEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent.html) which in turns offers you the [`getServletContext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent.html#getServletContext%28%29) method.

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        URL url = event.getServletContext().getResource(fileName);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Register it in `web.xml` as a `<listener>`.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: so, contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) method will be invoked automatically when the web app starts?

Comment: If registered in web.xml, yes. Note the blue text in my answer. Those are links. Click and read them.